# I'd like to know how to incorporate a CSS file into my Spring project that uses Thymeleaf while implementing a Login system

Tags: java, html, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Thank you for taking the time to read my message. I have experience with Java, but I'm currently facing a new challenge with Spring and Thymeleaf. I've been working on a login system and encountered a significant issue: I'm unable to successfully call files, such as photos or CSS files, from the static folder within the HTML files located in the resources folder. The files don't load at all. I suspect that this problem might be related to login "obfuscation", but I'm uncertain. I've tried various approaches to resolve it, but haven't found a solution yet. Could someone please assist me? For reference, I have provided the key classes from my project below.

MvCConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
    
}
```

WebSecConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/hello", true)
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
```

Login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="EN">
<head>
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style/login.css"
        th:href="@{/style/login.css}" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="login-container">
  <img src="../templates/imgs/bank.svg" alt="TrueBank">
  <h2>TrueBank Login</h2>
  <form id="login-form" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  document.getElementById('login-form').addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    try {
      const response = await fetch('/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
      });

      const data = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        // Login success
        alert(data.message);
        // Redirect to another page or perform other actions
      } else {
        // Login failure
        alert(data.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      alert('An error occurred');
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM7M9.png)

I attempted to include `@{/static/style/login.css}` in my project, but unfortunately, it was incorrect. I also attempted to replace `th:href` with `href` to avoid using it, but that approach did not work either.

Comment: All URLs are secured but `/` and `/login` add the `/static/**` to the list of public accessible URLs as wsell.